# Crystal reports 2008 report writing

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi
  I'm trying to write my first report!!!

and have number of question I cant seem to find the answer to can anyone help me please!

Q1.
  i drag a DB field on the the report which is a string format and need to divide the value by 1024 and display the result. I know i need to use tonumber({fieldname}] but don't know where or how to add this and then do the division. how do I do it?

Q2.
  on the report I have a group in its header I have the items that display across the report. in the detail I have the fields of a table that relate to above line. all good so far! How do add another Group or section that would allow another collection of data relating to the same first line!
 as I see it I need to add another group with another detail section but I can't do this!

Hope this make some sort of sense!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1:

That operation should be done in a formula -- the formula editor will provide views to functionality you can access in that context.

### Answer 2:

The Group Editor is what you need to use.  You can access it from one of the menus at the top, or by right clicking the row header for the appropriate section IIRC.

Comment: Thank you for you help but i think I need a book!!
I can fine the formula editor but have no Idea what I'm doing within it, I'm guess I need to build a new function, but think that will have to wait!


I can add another group section but it does not add a new detail section! If I add the fields to the new section header it only shows the first item and not all the items.
if I add all the information in the detailed section it repeats all information the number of time of the longest item, not sure that makes sense!

Comment: @Adrian: The Crystal Reports Developer software has documentation with it.  Been a while, but it was decent.  Other than that, look at other formulas if you have any other reports available.